# Swift HUD with an Synchronous API download

Tags: swift

I am trying to add a HUD effect to my page while I do a Synchronous download.

The HUD does not appear if I put into the viewDidLoad().

If I put into awakeFromNib() the screen will darken but the progress spinner does not appear.  (I have also tried ViewWillAppear)

I am using https://github.com/rjeprasad/RappleProgressHUD.

This has no effect when loading data. It only works for an instant after data loaded.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    RappleActivityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

   // the API function
    let a_Json = getDataJson(symbol: a)
    let b_Json = getdDataJson(symbol: b)

    RappleActivityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

}
```

Using Swift 4.2 and Alamofire_Synchronous for the API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the data loading in the background so the UI can keep running.

Here is the general pattern you want:

```
// start the activity indicator here

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // Data loading / processing here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // stop the activity indicator here and make any other UI updates
    }
}
```

In your specific case:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    RappleActivityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // the API function
        let a_Json = getDataJson(symbol: a)
        let b_Json = getdDataJson(symbol: b)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            RappleActivityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this was a new experience but I got it to work. looks really cool.  thanks!

Comment: having an issue with passing data into the dispatch? is there something special about it?  just adding self.  does not work.  thanks.

Comment: What issue? Be specific.

Comment: it appears that there is big issue with Realm data?  still trying to track down.